# C++ heap CPS: Continuation Passing Style with Recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, functional-programming, c++14, heap

I am willing to see how to write readable and efficient **continuations on the heap in c++**. I am not quite satisfied.

The following is just an exercise: it is coded for fun. I post the code here because I am not really satisfied. I am looking for suggestions. 
I picked up the simplest algorithm: measuring the length of a list and I wrote few recursive implementations. The plain one is `len()`.

Then I wrote `lenK()` i.e. len() in CPS. This is quite straightforward, I think this code is fine. Isn't it?

When it comes to Kontinuations on the heap, I had to write the continuation K as a class (fine) but I had to use virtuality to let the compiler understand what I wanted (if I use templates the compiler cannot understand that my program eventually terminates and for each call create a new type). I have the strong impression that my solution is not elegant and is not efficient. Is there a better way to implement CPS on the heap?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

struct List;
bool isEnd(const List& l);
double getHead(const List& l);
List* getTail(const List& l);
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
int len(const List& l, int val=0){
    if (isEnd(l))
        return val;
      return len(*getTail(l), 
                 ++val);
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

double lenK(const List& l, std::function<int(int)> k){
    if (isEnd(l))
        return k(0);
    return lenK(*getTail(l), [k](int a){return k(a+1);} );
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class IntInt{
   public:
      virtual ~IntInt()=default;
      virtual int operator()(int)=0;
};

using funcPtr = std::unique_ptr<IntInt>;

class IntID : public IntInt{
   public:
      int operator()(int a){ return a;}
};

class K : public IntInt{
   public:
      K( funcPtr&& k) : k_(std::move(k)){}
      int operator()(int a){ return (*k_)(a+1);}
   private:
      funcPtr k_;
};
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

double lenKheap(const List& l, funcPtr&& k){
    if (isEnd(l))
        return (*k)(0);
    List* myTail = getTail(l);  
    funcPtr myK = std::make_unique<K>(std::move(k));
    // Without tail call optimization we run out of stack space as for lenK and len. 
    return lenKheap(*myTail, 
                    std::move(myK));
}

void checkLenFunctions(const List& myL){

    std::cout << len(myL) << std::endl;

    auto intId = [](int x){return x;};
    std::cout << lenK(myL, intId ) << std::endl;

    std::cout << lenKheap(myL, std::make_unique<IntID>()) << std::endl;
}
```

If you want to experiment without bothering with the task of implementing the List class and functions, I provide you with an implementation of it. But this is not part of the review:

```
struct List{
    List(double d, List* l) : d_(d), l_(l){}
    List() : d_(0.0), l_(this){}
    double d_;
    List* l_;
};

bool isEnd(const List& l){
    if (l.l_ == &l)
        return true;
    return false;
}
double getHead(const List& l){
    if (!isEnd(l))
        return l.d_;
    throw "EndOfList";
}
List* getTail(const List& l){
    if (!isEnd(l))
        return l.l_;
    throw "EndOfList";
}

int main(){
    List myL;
    List myL1 = List(1.0, &myL);
    List myL2 = List(2.0, &myL1);
    List myL3 = List(3.0, &myL2);
    List myL4 = List(4.0, &myL3);

    checkLenFunctions(myL4);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's continuation *passing* style

Comment: I'd be glad to review this but I'm not sure how. What's the point of continuations on the heap? `std::function` might allocate some memory on the heap for all we know; having a `unique_ptr` handle instead doesn't seem to be a step forward. On the contrary that leads to very obfuscated a code.

Comment: @papagaga thanks for the name. This is just a case-study. I think that heap-based CPS is useful when stack is limited and recursion is deep. Especially in algorithms based on double recursion. I hope this does make sense.

Answer (score 2):

### Code Review

- Use standard library data structures! In this case `std::list`.
- Iterators are the usual way of traversing a C++ container, so use those too (they also allow us to not care which data structure is being used).
- Use `std::size_t` or even `std::container<T>::size_type` for indexing. An int is signed, and won't necessarily cover the correct range to be indexed.
- `lenK` and `lenKheap` return doubles, but should presumably return the index type.

```
template<class IteratorT>
std::size_t length(IteratorT begin, IteratorT end, std::size_t totalLength = 0) {
    return (begin == end) ? totalLength : length(std::next(begin), end, totalLength + 1);
}

using F = std::function<std::size_t(std::size_t)>;

template<class IteratorT>
std::size_t lengthK(IteratorT begin, IteratorT end, F k = [] (std::size_t a) { return a; }) {
    return (begin == end) ? k(0) : lengthK(std::next(begin), end, [k] (std::size_t a) { return k(a + 1); });
}

...

    auto list = std::vector<int>{ 0, 1, 2, 3 };

    std::cout << length(list.begin(), list.end()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << lengthK(list.begin(), list.end()) << std::endl;
```

---

Note that the stack overflow that happens with long lists is due to the depth of recursion. `std::function` may already be using the heap to allocate memory. As such, there's not much point in using `unique_ptr`.

In theory we could use the type hiding already present in `std::function`, rather than defining a separate inheritance hierarchy, and do something like this:

```
template<class IteratorT>
std::size_t lengthKHeap(IteratorT begin, IteratorT end, std::unique_ptr<F>&& k = std::make_unique<F>([] (std::size_t a) { return a; })) {
    return (begin == end) ? (*k)(0) : lengthKHeap(std::next(begin), end, std::make_unique<F>([k = std::move(k)](std::size_t a) { return (*k)(a + 1); }));
}
```

However, this doesn't compile. Although lambda capture by move was added in C++14, `std::function` is still required to be copyable. We can use a dodgy work-around storing the parameters in a shared pointer like this:

```
// hideous hack from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20846873/673679
template<class F>
auto make_copyable_function(F&& f) {
    auto spf = std::make_shared<std::decay_t<F>>(std::forward<F>(f));
    return [spf] (auto&&... args) -> decltype(auto) { return (*spf)(decltype(args)(args)...); };
}

template<class IteratorT>
std::size_t lengthKHeap(IteratorT begin, IteratorT end, std::unique_ptr<F>&& k = std::make_unique<F>([] (std::size_t a) { return a; })) {
    return (begin == end) ? (*k)(0) : lengthKHeap(std::next(begin), end, std::make_unique<F>(make_copyable_function([k = std::move(k)](std::size_t a) { return (*k)(a + 1); })));
}
```

But as mentioned, this doesn't help avoid the stack overflow.

---

### Deviations

Things become much more interesting if we stop using recursion and store a vector of functions instead. This allows us to make the control flow explicit (which appears to be one of the main points of using continuations). e.g.:

```
using NodeT = std::function<void()>;

struct Then {

    void add(NodeT node) {
        m_nodes.push_back(std::move(node));
    }

    void operator()() const {
        for (auto& n : m_nodes)
            n();
    }

private:

    std::vector<NodeT> m_nodes;
};

...

    auto i = 0;
    auto increment = [&] () { ++i; };

    auto then = Then();

    for (auto _ : list)
        then.add(increment);

    then();

    std::cout << i << std::endl;
```

Counting the elements in a list isn't a good example, but I've actually found this pattern of composing functions very helpful for writing lexers / parsers. By defining some more classes to go with `Then` (`Or`, `ZeroOrOne`, `ZeroOrMore`, etc.) and some operator overloading, it's possible to build up an entire tree of parsing / lexing functions with code that's [very close to a simple statement of the language grammar](https://bitbucket.org/mba105/calculator/src/default/lex.cpp). Which is pretty cool (if not technically continuations).

---

Of course, there's also asychronously oriented composition stuff using [`std::future`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future), but I've not been keeping up with what's going on in the C++ standard with that lately.

- [facebook version](https://code.fb.com/developer-tools/futures-for-c-11-at-facebook/).
- [blog series on avoiding allocations](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/zeroalloc_continuations_p0.html).

---

### Full Code

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

template<class IteratorT>
std::size_t length(IteratorT begin, IteratorT end, std::size_t totalLength = 0) {
    return (begin == end) ? totalLength : length(std::next(begin), end, totalLength + 1);
}

using F = std::function<std::size_t(std::size_t)>;

template<class IteratorT>
std::size_t lengthK(IteratorT begin, IteratorT end, F k = [] (std::size_t a) { return a; }) {
    return (begin == end) ? k(0) : lengthK(std::next(begin), end, [k] (std::size_t a) { return k(a + 1); });
}

// hideous hack from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20846873/673679
template<class F>
auto make_copyable_function(F&& f) {
    auto spf = std::make_shared<std::decay_t<F>>(std::forward<F>(f));
    return [spf] (auto&&... args) -> decltype(auto) { return (*spf)(decltype(args)(args)...); };
}

template<class IteratorT>
std::size_t lengthKHeap(IteratorT begin, IteratorT end, std::unique_ptr<F>&& k = std::make_unique<F>([] (std::size_t a) { return a; })) {
    return (begin == end) ? (*k)(0) : lengthKHeap(std::next(begin), end, std::make_unique<F>(make_copyable_function([k = std::move(k)](std::size_t a) { return (*k)(a + 1); })));
}

#include <functional>
#include <vector>

using NodeT = std::function<void()>;

struct Then {

    void add(NodeT node) {
        m_nodes.push_back(std::move(node));
    }

    void operator()() const {
        for (auto& n : m_nodes)
            n();
    }

private:

    std::vector<NodeT> m_nodes;
};

#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    {
        auto const list = std::vector<int>{ 0, 1, 2, 3 };

        {
            std::cout << length(list.begin(), list.end()) << std::endl;
            std::cout << lengthK(list.begin(), list.end()) << std::endl;
            std::cout << lengthKHeap(list.begin(), list.end()) << std::endl;
        }

        {
            auto i = 0;
            auto increment = [&] () { ++i; };

            auto then = Then();

            for (auto _ : list)
                then.add(increment);

            then();

            std::cout << i << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```